# Using existing class (js constructor) within mixin function

Tags: typescript, mixins, typescript-typings

There are [such example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html) in docs for mixins classes.

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function Tagged<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {
        _tag: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._tag = "";
        }
    }
}
```

But what if I already have implementations of `Tagged`. It looks like I just trying `Base extends Tagged`. But in my case `Tagged` have TypeScript implementation in one 3-d party lib and `Base` is JS constructor returned by factory method of other 3-d party lib.

What the best way to mix them? In other word, how define mixin class based on already existing class (code reuse)?

Answer (score -1):

In this example, `Tagged` takes a class, and returns an enhanced class. You cannot use it like this:

```
Base extends Tagged
```

because it's not `Base` that extends `Tagged` — it's the other way around.

If both the `Base` and `Tagged` are provided for you, you should be using them like so:

```
const MyExtendedClass = Tagged(Base);
new MyExtendedClass();
```

Comment: I know how use it. Question was about how define mixin class based on already existing class (code reuse).